# How to merge common items from the nested list c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics

I have the below list. This list needs to be self organized. Same "pname" catlist items with same categoryname items to be merged and needs to make it as single list as shown in the "Expected Result" Below

**Orginal List:**

```
{
    "expcatlist": [{
            "pnyrs": [{
                    "pns": [{
                            "pname": "abc",
                            "catlist": [{
                                    "categoryName": "dal",
                                    "explist": [{
                                            "expname": "xyz",
                                            "expdis": "xyz"
                                        }, {
                                            "expname": "uvw",
                                            "expdis": "uvw"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, ],
        }, {
            "pnyrs": [{
                    "pns": [{
                            "pname": "abc",
                            "catlist": [{
                                    "categoryName": "dal",
                                    "explist": [{
                                            "expname": "xyz",
                                            "expdis": "xyz"
                                        }, {
                                            "expname": "stv",
                                            "expdis": "stv"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, ],
        }, {
            "pnyrs": [{
                    "pns": [{
                            "pname": "def",
                            "catlist": [{
                                    "categoryName": "ghi",
                                    "explist": [{
                                            "expname": "jkl",
                                            "expdis": "jkl"
                                        },   {
                                            "expname": "mno",
                                            "expdis": "mno"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, ],
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
    "expcatlist": [{
            "pnyrs": [{
                    "pns": [{
                            "pname": "abc",
                            "catlist": [{
                                    "categoryName": "dal",
                                    "explist": [{
                                            "expname": "xyz",
                                            "expdis": "xyz"
                                        }, {
                                            "expname": "uvw",
                                            "expdis": "uvw"
                                        }, {
                                            "expname": "stv",
                                            "expdis": "stv"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, ],
        }, {
            "pnyrs": [{
                    "pns": [{
                            "pname": "def",
                            "catlist": [{
                                    "categoryName": "ghi",
                                    "explist": [{
                                            "expname": "jkl",
                                            "expdis": "jkl"
                                        },   {
                                            "expname": "mno",
                                            "expdis": "mno"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I would need help to build a LINQ statement to make the Original List self organized.

```
public class Catlist
{
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Explist> explist { get; set; }
}
public class Expcatlist
{
    public List<Pnyr> pnyrs { get; set; }
}
public class Explist
{
    public string expname { get; set; }
    public string expdis { get; set; }
}
public class Pn
{
    public string pname { get; set; }
    public List<Catlist> catlist { get; set; }
}
public class Pnyr
{
    public List<Pn> pns { get; set; }
}
public class Root
{
    public List<Expcatlist> expcatlist { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! can you beautify the json a bit? currently its quite difficult to see how the jsons compare at a glance. also, any particular rules for conflicting field before merging the objects? have you tried using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-8.0)?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. How do i beautify JSON?

Comment: please prettier the json  https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print and place in a "markdown code block"

Comment: @ematech - You've said you need help, but you haven't asked for specific help. You've just dumped JSON and code at us. Perhaps read [ask] and see if you can improve your question?

Comment: Also, think about what it would take for someone to answer. I would need the code that loads the JSON into the code you've provided. I'm not going to spend time doing that when you should already have it. Make it easy for us to answer your question.

Comment: @ematech so, you want to merge `catlist` of the same `pname` including its `explist`? you can solve this multiple ways. one of them is using linq `GroupBy` paired with `Select` (you have to be explicit). the other approaches would be using [tag:automapper] or even reflection directly (kinda complicated and expensive but mostly automated).

Comment: @ematech: one way to beautify your json would be to reduce the indents to 2 spaces. As it is, it's unreadable on a phone

Comment: I suggest you read up on `.GroupBy()`, `.SelectMany()`, and `.Distinct()`. Then make an attempt and if you still have problems. post your code, problem description, expected, and actual results back here.

Comment: Also, be sure to clearly state what your rules are for matching and combining objects. For example, your Expcatlist and Pnyr objects have no name or id, so under what conditions can they be combined?

Answer (score 0):

The way the json written is very complicated and the rule for merging `pnyrs` is not well established. Assuming we merge only the child of `Root -> pnyrs`, we could "recreate" the root while processing the leaves.

The code below is very **implicit** on handling the field merging. We use `GroupBy` extensively to "merge" same `pname`s and `expname`s. Then `Select` to take only the `Key` and relevant items from the group.

```
var new_Pnyrs =
    rt.expcatlist.SelectMany(
         expl => expl.pnyrs.SelectMany(pnrys => pnrys.pns))
        .GroupBy(pns => pns.pname)
        .Select(pns_g =>
                new Pn
                {
                    pname = pns_g.Key,
                    catlist = pns_g.SelectMany(pns => pns.catlist)
                        .GroupBy(catlist => catlist.categoryName)
                        .Select(catlist_g => 
                               new Catlist
                                {
                                    categoryName = catlist_g.Key,
                                    explist = catlist_g.SelectMany(catlist => catlist.explist)
                                        .GroupBy(explist => explist.expname)
                                        .Select(explist_g =>
                                                new Explist
                                                {
                                                    expname = explist_g.Key,
                                                    expdis = explist_g.First().expdis
                                                })
                                        .ToList()
                                })
                        .ToList()
                })
        .Select(pns =>
                new Pnyr
                {
                    pns = new List<Pn>(){ pns }
                })
        .ToList();
    
    var new_explist = new_Pnyrs.Select(np => new Expcatlist() { pnyrs  = new List<Pnyr>(){ np } }).ToList();
    var new_root = new Root(){ expcatlist = new_explist };
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new_root));
```

See Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qc3Sqe

There might be easier ways doing this which may involve reflections through [automapper](/questions/tagged/automapper), [Json Merge](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm), etc.